# How to create a new array using of another array keys?

Tags: php

Is it possible to create a new array from the keys of another like following?
it is a dynamic array chk_values are dynamically changed depends on condition
    Array
    (
        [actBtn] => update
        [chkCount] => 5
        [chk_1] => 2
        [chk_2] => 3
        [chk_3] => 2
        [chk_4] => 3
        [chk_5] => 3 
    )

and i want array like this for update database

```
$chckpoint = Array(   
    [chk_1] => 2
    [chk_2] => 3
    [chk_3] => 2
    [chk_4] => 3
    [chk_5] => 3)
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to code something to do this?

Comment: If you already know which array you expect, what's the problem? Do you want to compute that result array from dynamic input by any rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply process the original array and only move to the new array where the key starts with `chk_`

```
$in = ['actBtn' => 'update',
        'chkCount' => 5,
        'chk_1' => 2,
        'chk_2' => 3,
        'chk_3' => 2,
        'chk_4' => 3,
        'chk_5' => 3 
    ];

foreach($in as $k=>$v){
    if ( strpos($k,'chk_') !== false ){ $chckpoint[$k] = $v; }
}
print_r($chckpoint);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [chk_1] => 2
    [chk_2] => 3
    [chk_3] => 2
    [chk_4] => 3
    [chk_5] => 3
)
```

Comment: @MarkusZeller Hi, how am I not treating the array as immutable, I am making a copy of the original array. Much like you do in your answer I see

Answer (score 1):

You can simply take the input array and check for all keys beginning with `chk_`. If the key matches, take it to the new array.

```php
$chckpoint = [];
foreach($input as $key => $value)
{
    if(substr($key, 0, 4) == 'chk_') $chkpoint[$key] = $value;
}
```